# Direct entry blocked. Googlebot not enter my site

Tags: php, googlebot

I want to block direct entries to  my site. Please help me. İ want only googlebot,yandexbot enter my site(via google). I want googlebot enter my site.
my english bad sorry

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
if ( strpos($referer, 'google.com') === 
    FALSE && strpos($referer, 'google') === 
    FALSE && strpos($referer, 'googlebot') === 
    FALSE ) {
    echo "Bye Bye";
 ;}
```

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` is browser set so this wont stop any one with the most basic of skills

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Does robots.txt help? Something like:

```
useragent: *
disallow= /

useragent: google
allow= /
```

Comment: yes, my problem php code. Not robots.txt problem. thank :(